# what do comma operators do in an "eval()"?

Tags: java

I am trying to learn java, and ive come across this code in an old UIL practice test, and i can't figure out what this part of the code is doing.

```
d[i][j] = eval(d[i-1][j]+1
[i][j-1]+1, d[i-1][j-1] + cost); /* the commas confuse me, I don't know what to add to cost */
```

here is the whole code if it helps

```
private static int eval(int a, int b, int c) {
    int m;
    m = a;
    if (b < m)
        m = b;
    if (c < m)
        m = c;
    return m;
}

public static int comp(String s, String t) {

    int d[][];
    int n, m, i, j;
    char si, tj, cost;
    n = s.length();
    m = t.length();

    if (n == 0) {
        return m;
    }

    if (m == 0) {
        return n;
    }

    d = < * 1 >;

    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        d[i][0] = i;
    }

    for (j = 0; j <= m; j++) {
        d[0][j] = j;
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {

        si = s.charAt(i - 1);

        for (j = 1; j <= m; j++) {

            tj = t.charAt(j - 1);

            if (si == tj) {
                cost = 0;
            } else {
                cost = 1;
            }

            d[i][j] = eval(d[i - 1][j] + 1,
            d[i][j - 1] + 1, d[i - 1][j - 1] + cost);
        }
    }
    return d[n][m];
}
```

Comment: Please format your code.  (Use the **{ }** button in the editor.)

Comment: One comma is missing...

Comment: I suggest you give your method and variables meaningful names.  As you can see it is very hard for you and also for use to work out what your program does and why when you use generic names.

Comment: what a nice method name `eval()`, I thought of another `eval()`.... I just googled, if `eval()` was added into the latest release of Jdk....... :(

Answer (score 1):

Comma in method is used to separate arguments.

As you can see `eval` methods need tree arguments

```
private static int eval (int a, int b, int c){
```

and in your code example you are invoking it like this

```
        d[i][j] = eval(d[i - 1][j] + 1, //<-there is comma here in your code
        d[i][j - 1] + 1, d[i - 1][j - 1] + cost);
```

which is equal to

```
d[i][j] = eval(d[i-1][j]+1, d[i][j-1]+1, d[i-1][j-1] + cost);
```

so argument `a` will be value of `d[i-1][j]+1`, `b` = `d[i][j-1]+1` and `c`=`d[i-1][j-1] + cost`

Answer (score 0):

The commas are there simply to separate the different arguments to a method call, `eval()` in this case. For example, if we were to call `eval()` like this:

```
eval(1, 2, 3)
```

Then, inside `eval()`'s body the parameters will be bound like this:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java comma is never an operator.  It is always just a separator.

```
    d[i][j] = eval(d[i - 1][j] + 1,
                   d[i][j - 1] + 1, 
                   d[i - 1][j - 1] + cost);
```

In this context, it just separates the actual argument expressions in a method call.  (I have fixed the indentation to make this clear.)

So in your example, the commas just separate the 3 argument expressions for an `eval` call.  Maybe you were just mislead by some "non-standard" indentation.

---

(In C and C++, there *is* a [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator); e.g.

```
    a = x(), y();
```

would mean call `x` and discard the result, then call `y` and assign the result to `a`.  However, that statement is not valid Java code.)